# Textview show partial text

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, word-wrap

I have a TextView in which I must load a message. The TextView has maximum 2 lines (`android:lines="2"`). The message may contain an '\n' character.

How should I load the message in that TextView so that words would be wrapped and if in those 2 lines message does not fit, at the end of last visible word I must add three dots (...)? How can I detect the length of text that fits in that TextView?

My code for TextView is

```
<TextView
            a:id="@+id/tv_message"
            a:gravity="top"
            a:layout_width="wrap_content"
            a:layout_height="wrap_content"
            a:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            a:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_icon"
            a:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            a:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            a:paddingRight="7dp"
            a:paddingBottom="5dp"
            a:textSize="12sp"
            a:typeface="sans"
            a:ellipsize="marquee"
            a:lines="2"
            a:maxLines="2"
            a:textColor="@android:color/black"
            />
```

But in application, text appears on two lines, even if there is a line containing the signature. The message is like: "message text" + "\nSignature" but the message can be on 1,2,3 lines, depending of message length.

Comment: Why do you need to know the length of the text? It may vary for different screen sizes, unless you define a fixed width for the TextView.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to add 3 dots at the end of last visible word. android:ellipsize="end" and android:ellipsize="marquee" doesn't help.... so I thought that I don't add all text to textview, but only the text that fits the textview

Comment: can you post the code for the TextView that you are using now? maybe there are other properties that prevent the ellipsize one to works.

Answer (score 25):

In XML, use the property  `android:ellipsize="marquee"`for the TextView.

Your TextView can be defined like:

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/text" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:maxLines="2" 
android:lines="2" 
android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

**Edit**: I've tried the following code, adapted from yours:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlt_news"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/cell_background"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rss_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="100dip"
        android:maxWidth="100dip"
        android:src="@drawable/rss_cell_icon"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rss_icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:lines="2"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="7dp"
        android:text="Description of the news, just the short paragraph, \nSignature, to see how it works if there are more than two lines"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the output:
[image]

Comment: it doesn't help... If I have message: line1 \nline2 \nline3 after line2 I must add 3 dots because the message didn't fit

Comment: did you try to to use this attribute? It just truncate the text after the second line and put the three dots for you, I cut and paste it from my code.

Comment: I have replaced my code with yours and it works, I posted a picture with the results...I don't know what happens there, maybe you are setting some of the properties in the code also? Or it's just that I don't understand what you want.. Have you also tried the new solution provided by @slup?

Comment: yes, I'm setting the text from code... may be this a problem?

Comment: No, I'm setting the text from the code also; here I just put it in the XML for you to see what text I've used, but I have the same effect with the text from code.  But I thought there may be other properties you are setting by code, beside the text, that can interfere.

Answer (score 12):

Use `android:ellipsize="end"` instead of "marquee" that did it for me.

Answer (score 8):

Gabi,

I was also having the same problem. To enable ellipsize on a textview with 2 lines I use the following parameters:

```
android:maxLines="2"   // You already got this one
android:ellipsize="end" // also this one
android:singleLine="false"  // This is the command that solves your problem.
```

Unfortunately I got a new scenario for my app. I have to use 3 lines with ellipsize and this configuration only works for 2 lines... :( Good luck

Comment: @Gasper it worked for me. I apply for 1 line. Thank you somuch.

Answer (score 4):

If you set text from code, than you must set options once again!

```
textView.setText(content);
textView.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
textView.setLines(5);
textView.setMaxLines(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me when I set it in code not in the XML layout

```
holder.txtDescription.setText(text);
holder.txtDescription.setMaxLines(3);
holder.txtDescription.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s = "line1 \nline2 \nline3";
    String [] lines = s.split("\n");
    String twolines;
    if (lines.length > 2) {
        twolines = lines[0] + "\n" + lines[1] + "...";
    } else {
        twolines = s;
    }
```

This should give you the desired result, just use

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(twolines);
```

Comment: it doesn't help... If I have message: line1 \nline2 \nline3 after line2 I must add 3 dots because the message didn't fit

Comment: but the first line of message may be long enough to fit on 3 lines of textview, so this doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" did the trick for me. Text size reduces to fit available space but complete text is displayed.

Refer this link
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/autosizing-textview